# Distributivity of pullbacks

Tags: category-theory

If we consider morphisms $A\rightarrow C\leftarrow B$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$, then we denote their pullback by $A\leftarrow A\times_{C}B\rightarrow B$. The question is the following: is it true that there is an isomorphism $$\Big(A_{1}\coprod A_{2}\Big)\times_{C} B\cong A_{1}\times_{C}B\coprod A_{2}\times_{C}B?$$ If not, when does this hold?

Comment: This fails for $C=0$ in the category of $k$-vector spaces (where both products and coproducts are direct sums).

Comment: Ok, so this isn't true in general. Do you know when does this hold?

Answer (score 1):

The condition says that every slice category $\mathcal{C}/C$ is [distributive](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+category). This usually fails in abelian categories. It holds in every topos, in the category of topological spaces and in the category of schemes.

Comment: This is essentially the definition of a lextensive category.